# Xcode: 'ModuleNotFoundError'

Tags: python, xcode, module, kivy

I am trying to run an app I have built using python and kivy. I have created an Xcode file which builds successfully, but when I simulate the app in Xcode the following error message is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/orlandoalexander/alarmclock-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 11, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osascript'
2021-03-07 20:39:05.124675+0000 alarmclock[2937:103283] Application quit abnormally!
2021-03-07 20:39:05.156979+0000 alarmclock[2937:103283] Leaving
```

Why would this be? Do I need to import the module 'osascript' into Xcode in some way?

I have installed osascript using pip3 via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing osascript using

> pip install osascript

Or u need to update the pip package (windows)

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to make a difference... Any other ideas? (I'm on Mac btw)